# Hybris fails when is the code is auto generating - ant all

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am working with the  5.7 version of Hybris platform and JAVA 1.8.0.77, when I am doing the **ant all** with the customer data, it fails everytime:

> ```
> [ycodegenerator] 11:14:23,475 [main] INFO  DtoClassGenerator -    Generating resources ..
> [ycodegenerator] 11:14:28,785 [main] INFO  CodeGenerator - Code generation done in 25957 ms. 
>      [echo]       building models from C:\Hybris2\hybris\bin\platform/bootstrap/gensrc to C:\Hybris2\hybris\bin\platform/bootstrap/bin/models.jar 
>     [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Hybris2\hybris\bin\platform\bootstrap\modelclasses 
>    [yjavac] Compiling 1563 source files to C:\Hybris2\hybris\bin\platform\bootstrap\modelclasses 
>    [yjavac] ----------
>    [yjavac] 1. ERROR in C:\Hybris2\hybris\bin\platform\bootstrap\gensrc\br\com\carrefour\facades\payment\GiftCardPaymentInfoData.java <at line 22>
>    [yjavac]     import de.klatform.commercefacades.order.data.AbstractPaymentInfoData;
>    [yjavac]            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    [yjavac] The import de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.data.AbstractPaymentInfoData cannot be resolved
> ```
>
> [image: Console Log]

I can't see what I am missing.

here is the LocalExtensions.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources/schemas/extensions.xsd">
    <extensions>
        <!-- 
                All extensions located in ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform/ext are automatically loaded. 
                More information about how to configure available extensions can be found here : https://wiki.hybris.com/x/nZVzC
        -->
                
        <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />
        
        <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-commerce"/>
        
        
<!--        <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/ext-addon/addonsupport"/> -->
            
            
        <extension name="addonsupport"/>
        <extension name="mediaconversion"/>
    
        <extension name="carrefourcockpits" />
        <extension name="carrefourcore" />
        <extension name="carrefourfacades" />

        <extension name="carrefouroms" />
        <extension name="carrefourinitialdata" />
        <extension name="carrefourstorefront" />
        <extension name="carrefourintegrationws" /> 
        <extension name="carrefourinterfacews"/>
        
<!--        <extension name="carrefourtest" /> -->
        <extension name='carrefourhmc' />
        <extension name="carrefourcheckoutaddon"/>
        <extension name='carrefourcmscomponentsaddon' />
        
        <extension name="braspagintegration" />
        <extension name="clearsaleintegration" />
        
        <extension name="krsfacades" />
        <extension name="krsservices" />
        <extension name="krsasm"/>
        <extension name="krsasmstorefront"/>
        
        <extension name="backoffice" />
        <extension name="commercesearch" />
        <extension name="commercesearchbackoffice" />
        <extension name="commercesearchhmc" />

        <extension name="zipzonedeliverycore" />
        <extension name="zipzonedeliveryhmc" />
        <extension name="zipzonedeliveryfacades" />
        
        <extension name="voucher" />
        <extension name="voucherbackoffice" />
        
        <extension name="vouchers" />
        
        <extension name="solrfacetsearch" />
        <extension name="solrserver" />
        
        <!--  SAC extensions -->
        <extension name="carrefoursacstorefront" />
        <extension name="carrefoursaccore" />
        <extension name="carrefoursacfacades" />
        
        <!-- ASM -->
        <extension name="assistedservicestorefront"/>
        <extension name="acceleratorstorefrontcommons" />
        <extension name="assistedservicefacades"/>
        
        <!-- SSO -->
<!--        <extension name="samlsinglesignon"/> -->
<!--        <extension name="krssso"/> -->
        
        <!-- OMS -->
        <extension name="warehousing"/>
        <extension name="warehousingbackoffice"/>
        <extension name="ordermanagementbackoffice"/>
        <extension name="platformwebservices"/>
        
        <!-- data hub -->
        <extension name='datahubadapter' />
        <extension name='datahubbackoffice' />
        
        <!-- analytics and business events for hybris marketing integration -->
         <extension dir='${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/hybrisanalyticsaddon'/>
        
        <extension name='eventtrackingservices' />
        <extension name='eventtrackingmodel' />
        <extension name='eventtrackingpublisher' />
        <extension name='eventtrackingwsaddon' />
        
        <!-- yMkt integration -->
        <extension dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/custom/ypshybrismarketing/ymkt-hybris/cpoexport"/>

        <extension name='yc4ccarrefour' />
        <extension name='krsorderstatus' />
        
        <extension name="wishlist"/>
    </extensions>
</hybrisconfig>
```

carrefoursacfacades

[resources CarrefourFacades](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfKWX.png)

GiftCardPayment Definition

```
package br.com.carrefour.core.jalo;

import de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item;
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloBusinessException;
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.SessionContext;
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.type.ComposedType;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class GiftCardPayment extends GeneratedGiftCardPayment
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( GiftCardPayment.class.getName() );
    
    @Override
    protected Item createItem(final SessionContext ctx, final ComposedType type, final ItemAttributeMap allAttributes) throws JaloBusinessException
    {
        // business code placed here will be executed before the item is created
        // then create the item
        final Item item = super.createItem( ctx, type, allAttributes );
        // business code placed here will be executed after the item was created
        // and return the item
        return item;
    }
    
}
```

Item Creation

```
    <itemtype code="GiftCardPayment" extends="PaymentMode">
        <attributes>
            <attribute qualifier="maximumGiftCardAmount" autocreate="true"
                type="java.lang.Integer">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
                <persistence type="property" />
            </attribute>
            <attribute qualifier="valueGiftCard" autocreate="true"
                type="java.lang.Double">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" />
                <persistence type="property" />
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
    </itemtype>
    <itemtype code="BoletoPayment" extends="paymentmode">
        <description>Boleto Payment</description>
    </itemtype>
```

Comment: We need the error message and probably your localextensions.xml file

Comment: Hi Just added the localExtensions,  I have attached  an Image  of the console log. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have `commercefacades` in your localextensions.xml which is where `AbstractPaymentInfoData` is declared.
Either you add it explictly to your localextensions.xml or you declare it as dependency in your `carrefourcore` (or whereever your failing `GiftCardPaymentInfoData` is defined) `extensioninfo.xml' file by adding a line like:

```
<requires-extension name="commercefacades"/>
```

If that doesn't help, please post the part of the console log when the ant task lists the complete hybris extension dependency list, like this.
(commercefacades should show up there somewhere)

```
 [echo] ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [echo] --- Extensions in dependency order ( options: 
 [echo] ---  @deprecated: is deprecated, p: platform extension,*: auto-required 
 [echo] ---  ?: lazy-loaded, i: got items.xml, b: got beans.xml, c: got core module 
 [echo] ---  w: got web module, h: got HMC module ) 
 [echo] ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [echo] core 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*cib]
 [echo] testweb 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*w]
 [echo] scripting 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*ci]
 [echo] paymentstandard 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*ci]
 [echo] mediaweb 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*cw]
 [echo] maintenanceweb 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*w]
 [echo] deliveryzone 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*ci]
 [echo] commons 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [p*ci]
 [...]
 [echo] mcc->(impex,processing,cockpit) 6.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT [ciw] path:/Users/sebastianschaer/dev/bitwisers/code/ruleenginesuite/hybris/bin/ext-cockpit/mcc
 [echo] ---------------------------------------------------------------
 [echo]
```

**Alternative**: 
If this error isn't due to a missing extension (I don't have AbstractPaymentInfoData declared in commercefacades, but I'm working on a newer version rightn ow) it might be that your bean definition for GiftCardPaymentInfoData extends a wrong type, i.e. a non-existing one.
Are you migrating from an older hybris version to 5.7?

If so, maybe you need to change your bean definition for the GiftCardPaymentInfoData (declared in one of your extensions in the EXTENSION_NAME-beans.xml file) and change it to extend maybe `de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.order.data.CCPaymentInfoData` or `de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.payment.data.PaymentInfoData` or another already existing DTO..
If you are migrating you should look up the migration docs on the hybris wiki to see what changes were made regarding this.

Hope this helps,

Sebastian

Comment: How come you have Hybris 6 already ?
With Hybris 5.7 Commerce Facade has no AbstractPaymentInfoData.

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt I do product development for hybris :) 
And yes, likewise in 6.0, AbstractPaymentInfoData doesn't exist. I thought maybe that the extension and their DTOs were depending on an older hybris version that maybe had AbstractPaymentInfoData, but that might not be the case either. Maybe it's simply a wrong declaration in the *-beans.xml file?

Comment: I guess it's hopeless to ask you to send me Hybris 6 ahah :) 
I don't see any reference to AbstractPaymentInfoData under version 5.

Comment: @LiiTo Olivera could you do a grep under your bin directory ? Something like : grep -ri 'AbstractPayment' --include "*items.xml" .

Comment: Benoit, haha, yeah sorry, I'd get in serious trouble. But the other day there was a 6.0 system demo for partners and a recording  will soon be added to the wiki somewhere.
@LiiToOlivera
The grep would have to be over "*-beans.xml" files though, as the DTOs are defined in the <EXTENSIONNAME>-beans.xml files (not sure though if you have cygwin or some other grep tool on your windows box :) )

Comment: Sorry Guys it's useless, can get a work around.  Never mind, will create a ticket. FYI in the hybris wiki  I only saw until de version 5.7.0.9

Comment: You need to check all custom extensions and look for something like this under your beans.xml files :
<bean name="GiftCardPaymentInfo" extends="AbstractPaymentInfo"></bean>
Most likely as you said the client code you are importing is not compatible

Answer (score 0):

First thing try to clean your localextensions.xml file, for example only on path tag is required.

How did you generate it ? Did you use any installer ?

Have you tried 'ant clean all', it seems that GiftCardPaymentData has a missing dependency on AbstractPaymentInfo, on a local install of Hybris 5.7 I only have PaymentInfo I think you have added legacy source code ?

If the "ant clean all" doesn't fix your issue could you share the items.xml file of you carrefourfacades extension ?

Comment: The platform it self works fine, the problem is when I start adding the customer code.That's why I have  the localextensions with so many extensions.  I tried with the ant clean all, but same out come. I just added a screen shot of the facedes resourse, it doesn't have a items.xml.  Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: In what extension is GiftCardPayment defined ? Can you add the item definition

Comment: Is defined in carrefourcore, I added the item definition

Comment: What is customer code ? And from what Hybris version ? You need to look for the extension / file with GiftCardPayment and or AbstractPaymentInfo